# Replace empty cells with NaNs in pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I need to plot the content of a csv file. The table in the file contains several empty cells which should be replaced by NaNs so that, plotting the data with the `unbounded coords=jump` option would interrupt the plot at the positions of the missing values.

I thought of using the `empty cells with` key, but it doesn't work as expected. In the following example, the first table contains empty cells which are automatically replaced by NaNs, and doesn't work; the second table already contains NaNs cells and works properly instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% the next table won't work properly
\begin{filecontents}{testtablea.csv}
a;b
0;0
1;1
2;2
3;2
4;2
5;2
6;
7;
8;2
9;1
10;0
\end{filecontents}

% this will work instead
\begin{filecontents}{testtableb.csv}
a;b
0;0
1;1
2;2
3;2
4;2
5;2
6;NaN
7;NaN
8;2
9;1
10;0
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableset{empty cells with={NaN}}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{testtable1.csv}\testtablea
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{testtable2.csv}\testtableb
\begin{document}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\testtablea}\hspace{3cm}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\testtableb}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [title=automatic replacement, anchor=north east, width=7cm]
\addplot+ [unbounded coords=jump] table {\testtablea};
\end{axis}
\hspace{1cm}

\begin{axis} [title=well defined table, anchor=north west, width=7cm]
\addplot+ [unbounded coords=jump] table {\testtableb};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: wrong and correct behaviour]

So the question is:

1) how can I replace the empty cells in the original csv file by means of `pgfplotstable` to reach my goal?

or

2) how can I directly skip the empty values in a `pgfplot` (that is without `pgfplotstable`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With package `ifthen` you could add

```
y filter/.code={\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\def\pgfmathresult{nan}}{}}
```

as plot option or axis option.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepackage{ifthen}% <- added
% the next table won't work properly
\begin{filecontents}{testtablea.csv}
a;b
0;0
1;1
2;2
3;2
4;2
5;2
6;
7;
8;2
9;1
10;0
\end{filecontents}

% this will work instead
\begin{filecontents}{testtableb.csv}
a;b
0;0
1;1
2;2
3;2
4;2
5;2
6;NaN
7;NaN
8;2
9;1
10;0
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableset{empty cells with={NaN}}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{testtablea.csv}\testtablea
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{testtableb.csv}\testtableb
\begin{document}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\testtablea}\hspace{3cm}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\testtableb}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [title=automatic replacement, anchor=north east, width=7cm]
\addplot+[
  y filter/.code={\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\def\pgfmathresult{nan}}{}},% <- added
  unbounded coords=jump
]  table {\testtablea};
\end{axis}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{axis} [title=well defined table, anchor=north west, width=7cm]
\addplot+ [unbounded coords=jump] table {\testtableb};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's a typo in the package name on the first line.