# How to plot a graph even when data is missing?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to plot data where sometimes there are no data available and to avoid cleaning manualy the data file by removing the cocnerned lines, I want to know if there is an option to skip the void data (not treat as 0) as in the example, for case a and c (see below)? So here in the example I want just to plot b and d where the values are known with the 4 xticks shown.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{example.txt}
a  
b 0.995 
c 
d 5.722
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[ 
ylabel={Y}, 
xlabel={X}, 
symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d}, 
xtick={a,b,c,d},
xticklabels={AAAA,BBBB, CCCC,DDDD} 
] 
\addplot +[only marks,color=red] table[header=false] {example.txt}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a good candidate for **IF y=null THEN ignore ELSE do** however I do not know how / where to suggest best you inject that **case test**. but may hint to solutions.

Comment: This time I spent more time to find a potential partner question and got https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/366757/121799. (My problem is that even your original code does not run through on my machine since the very first data line has only one instead of two entries.)